# Как правильно сделать sql запрос Yii

Tags: sql, yii

Использую вот такой запрос для получения данных через модельку:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
                    $criteria->join = 'INNER JOIN orders ON t.id = orders.id_todo ';
                    $criteria->condition = 'orders.id_user_send = '.Yii::app()->user->id;
                    $todos = Todo::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Вопрос: как получить еще одну переменную в запросе в которой будет хранится подсчет других записей связанных с этой таблицей? Чтобы потом можно было получить результат вот так:

```
echo $todos->count_or;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если знаний не хватает - просто напишите запрос в sql редакторе, выполните, а затем переносите в yii

```
  $connection = Yii::app()->db;
    $sql = "
                            SELECT * from data
                            ";
    $dataReader = $connection->createCommand($sql)->query();
    $rows = $dataReader->readAll();
```